# How to prevent pdf-view from rounding highlight borders?

Tags: pdf, pdf-tools

When I highlight text in a PDF file in Emacs¹ using PDFView² the borders of the highlighed text are rounded:

[image: Highlighted text in Emacs]

---

Is it possible to get straight borders, like in masterpdfeditor³?:

[image: Highlighted text in masterpdfeditor]

Notes

1. `GNU Emacs 28.2 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.5, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2022-11-08`
2. `Version: 20221007.1404`
3. `Build 5.8.70, 64 bit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDF-View uses the [poppler library](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/), which does not support configuring the shape of the highlight (see [reference](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/api/glib/poppler-Poppler-Annotation.html#poppler-annot-text-markup-new-highlight)). There exists [an alternative pdf-server](https://pypi.org/project/vimura-server/) which uses (py)mupdf, but its highlights use very similar shapes.

Comment: Thanks! Just asked them for the feature https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/issues/1325